# Chrome PDF viewer malfunctioning when extension in started

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which allows to write on screen in chrome tabs. The default behaviour looks like :

[image]

It works be simply inserting a `canvas` tag in the DOM and doing all the stuff in it. It works well in all sites. However, chrome PDF viewer behaves strangely when I use it :

Before -
[image]

After -
[image]

I don't think there is any issue with the extension because it works on all other sites. I think there is an issue with chrome PDF viewer itself.

I can attach the code here if asked in comments.

Comment: I'd love to have a link to download the chrome extension to be able to test it, thanks in advance !

Comment: @CreaZyp154 It's not on the chrome webstore. You can download it from https://github.com/PraneetDixit/Draw-On-Screen/archive/main.zip and manually install it.

Comment: The built-in PDF viewer uses a standard DOM page to embed its internal plugin so evidently there's a conflict with something your extension does. Use devtools to compare the DOM of the tab when your extension is disabled and then when it's enabled.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, the DOM structure is changing about completely when the extension is enabled. But I don't know how it is happening because the extension is only adding elements to DOM, not changing the existing ones.

Comment: Strangely, when I toggle the extension with the devtools open, it (chrome devtool) automatically closes.

Comment: @PraneetDixit I'm trying to install the extension but it says : Could not unzip extension for install.

Comment: @CreaZyp154 You will need a software like WinZip to unzip it first and then install it.

Comment: Your extension **destroys** and then rebuilds the entire DOM of the page by appending to document.body.innerHTML. Use the nondestructive ways like insertAdjacentHTML or createElement + appendChild.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I tried to replace all `innerHTML += <value>;` by `insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",<value>);` And now it's working fine.

It's because your canvas must be on top to ensure it will works on every website.

The `z-index` propery is not enough for that.

Hope that helped !

Comment: Thanks. As @wOxxOm said, this was happening due to rewriting of entire DOM. Replacing `innerHTML += <value>` solved it.